# *First* Longest Increasing Subsequence

Tags: java, algorithm

The longest increasing subsequence is the well known problem and I have a solution with the patience algorithm.

Problem is, my solution gives me the "Best longest increasing sequence" instead of the *First* longest increasing sequence that appears.

The difference is that some of the members of the sequence are larger numbers in the first(but the sequence length is exactly the same).

Getting the first sequence is turning out to be quite harder than expected, because having the best sequence doesn't easily translate into having the first sequence.

I've thought of doing my algorithm then finding the first sequence of length N, but not sure how to.

So, how would you find the *First* longest increasing subsequence from a sequence of random integers?

My code snippet:

```
  public static void main (String[] args) throws java.lang.Exception {

        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));

        int inputInt;
        int[] intArr;

        try {
            String input = br.readLine().trim();
            inputInt = Integer.parseInt(input);
            String inputArr = br.readLine().trim();
            intArr = Arrays.stream(inputArr.split(" ")).mapToInt(Integer::parseInt).toArray();
        } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
            System.out.println("Could not parse integers.");
            return;
        }
        if(inputInt != intArr.length) {
            System.out.println("Invalid number of arguments.");
            return;
        }

        ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>> sequences = new ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>>();

        int sequenceCount = 1;
        sequences.add(new ArrayList<Integer>());
        sequences.get(0).add(0);

        for(int i = 1; i < intArr.length; i++) {
            for(int j = 0; j < sequenceCount; j++) {

                if(intArr[i] <= intArr[sequences.get(j).get(sequences.get(j).size() - 1)]) {
                    sequences.get(j).remove(sequences.get(j).size() - 1);
                    sequences.get(j).add(i);
                    break;
                } else if (j + 1 == sequenceCount) {
                    sequences.add(new ArrayList<Integer>(sequences.get(j)));
                    sequences.get(j + 1).add(i);
                    sequenceCount++;
                    break; //increasing sequenceCount causes infinite loop
                } else if(intArr[i] < intArr[sequences.get(j + 1).get(sequences.get(j + 1).size() - 1)]) {
                    sequences.set(j+ 1, new ArrayList<Integer>(sequences.get(j)));
                    sequences.get(j+ 1).add(i);
                    break;
                }
            }           
        }
        int bestSequenceLength = sequenceCount;
        ArrayList<Integer> bestIndexes = new ArrayList<Integer>(sequences.get(bestSequenceLength - 1));

        //build bestSequence, then after it I'm supposed to find the first one instead
        int[] bestSequence = Arrays.stream(bestIndexes.toArray()).mapToInt(x -> intArr[(int) x]).toArray();

       StringBuilder output = new StringBuilder("");
       for(Integer x : bestSequence) {
        output.append(x + " ");
       }
        System.out.println(output.toString().trim());
      }
```

I'm storing indexes instead in preparation for having to access the original array again. Since it's easier to go from indexes to values than vice versa.

Example:

3 6 1 2 8

My code returns: 1 2 8

First sequence is: 3 6 8

Another Example:

1 5 2 3

My code correctly returns: 1 2 3

Basically, my code works as long as the first longest sequence is the same as the best longest sequence. But when you have a bunch of longest sequences of the same length, it grabs the best one not the first one.

Comment: It would be easier to understand with an example.

Comment: if what you need is the length of the growing sequence, what you need is the starting index and the length of the max so far and of the current one. And you change the max one only when you have a better one. Going for a list of list looks overly complex

Comment: Added an example for clarification

Comment: @Helsing do I understand it correctly that your sequence can have gaps? So they must not be consecutive?

Comment: @Lino
Yes, exactly

Comment: that's not a sequence then... so yes you need a list of all possible sequences. But still think that storing starting index + length would be cleaner

Comment: what would be the expected result for input ```3 7 1 5 6 8```? ```3 7 8``` or ```3 5 6 8```?

Comment: @Wisthler it would be 3 5 6 8. It wants the longest one possible, but then first one that shows up from those.

Comment: @mahieus problem is I never build the first and longest sequence. For example:
3 6 1 2 8, I never build 3 6 8,because it gets replaced by 1,2 and so on.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Code is self-explanatory. (Have added comments, let me know if you need something extra).

```
public class Solution {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int[] arr = {3,6,1,2,8};
        System.out.println(solve(arr).toString());
    }

    private static List<Integer> solve(int[] arr){
        int[][] data = new int[arr.length][2];
        int max_length = 0;
        // first location for previous element index (for backtracing to print list) and second for longest series length for the element
        for(int i=0;i<arr.length;++i){
            data[i][0] = -1; //none should point to anything at first
            data[i][1] = 1;
            for(int j=i-1;j>=0;--j){
                if(arr[i] > arr[j]){
                    if(data[i][1] <= data[j][1] + 1){ // <= instead of < because we are aiming for the first longest sequence
                        data[i][1] = data[j][1] + 1;
                        data[i][0] = j;
                    }
                }
            }

            max_length = Math.max(max_length,data[i][1]);
        }

        List<Integer> ans = new ArrayList<>();

        for(int i=0;i<arr.length;++i){
            if(data[i][1] == max_length){
                int curr = i;
                while(curr != -1){
                    ans.add(arr[curr]);               
                    curr = data[curr][0];
                }                
                break;
            }
        }

        Collections.reverse(ans);// since there were added in reverse order in the above while loop
        return ans;
    }    
}
```

**Output:**

```
[3, 6, 8]
```

Comment: Amazing! It correctly finds the first LIS instead of the best. It ran out of memory before your fix but now it works for big inputs too. I'll give the others a chance before I select your answer as best answer but I don't think it'll get better than this.

Comment: @Helsing As you please. Glad to help. By the way, it was an interesting question. +1.

Comment: @Helsing Your question is combination of dynamic programming and greedy topics of CS where we use DP to find the longest and use greedy approach to find the first one.

Comment: It was a good educational experience. I edited the answer a little to allow the removal of the if statement when building the array.

Comment: @Helsing Nice. You are correct. We can get rid of that `if` statement.